# Read video file from middle

Tags: node.js, html, express, video-streaming, video.js

I want to stream video in small chunks eg: 0-50,50-100 etc.Able to play video when reading from 0.Unable to play video from random ranges.Thanks in advance.

```
createReadStream(path,{start:100000 end:200000 })
res.writeHead(206, {
        "Content-Range": "bytes 100000 - 200000 / 250000" ,
        "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
        "Content-Length": 100001,
        "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t work that way. You cant grab a random chunk of an MP4 and play it. You must located the moov box, and use that to determine at what byte offset the frame you wish to play is located. Then start decoding from that exact offset.